# Dynamic Color Change of Xml Style

Tags: android, xml, dynamic, colors, styles

I am trying to make a shape, which changes according to the topic of item in the listview. Here is what I need to do; a thin border around my circle area   [image]

My xml style is **cw_full_oval**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="100dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="100dp"
        android:topRightRadius="100dp" />
    <!--solid android:color="" / inner side full color-->
    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />
    <size
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/red_200" />
</shape>
enter code here
```

**Here is main part of Layout xml that I need it in a shape**

```
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/cw_full_oval"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/cw_full_oval"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/lin_lay_item_etkinlik_gl"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
```

**Image of my linearlayouts like below when I set styles from** *xml*

[image]

**In my adapter class I am trying to give my method, topic name and current linearlayout**

```
String nameOfObj = currentActivity.getName();
Util.getInstance(context).setColor(nameOfObj,holder.lin_lay_etkinlik);
```

**This method is not enough I know, just trying to describe what I need**

```
 public void setColor(String name, LinearLayout linlay){

        switch (name){
            case "Sinema":
                linlay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sinema);
                break;
            case "Piknik":
                linlay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.piknik);
                break;
            case "Futbol":
                linlay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.futbol);
                break;
            case "Gezi":
                linlay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gezi);
                break;
            case "Yemek":
                linlay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.yemek);
                break;
            case "Sohbet":
                linlay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sohbet);
                break;
            case "Cay":
                linlay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.cay);
                break;
            case "Toplantı":
                linlay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.sinema);
                break;
            default:
                linlay.setBackgroundResource(R.color.genel);
                break;
        }
    }
```

**And finally my method returns me** [image]

**How Can I fix it ?**

Well I dont have to obey my strategy, any other pratical solutions would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make the inner layout circular too.

You have too options:

1-Create circle drawables with your desired fill color. Since you are not making the drawable perfectly circle (if will want to, you just need the shape as circle of your drawable) you need to make the same configurations in the new drawable.

2-Make a drawable for each color and make the fill color inside, you already have it done, you just need to uncomment the fill color part.

Comment: I fixed my need. The way you described also passed from my mind thanks. I created some round images and imported them to my drawable so insead of colors I injected images, but would like to know if there is a aw yo control xml style would be more eficcent.